# Jersey API for network error handling

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I use `Jersey` to implement `REST` web services. Suppose a method of a `Resource` object returns a response and a network error occurs during sending the response to the client. Does `Jersey` provide any API to handle such an error?

Answer (score 2):

No, in HTTP it is the responsibility of the client to ask again if it didn't receive the response.